# Synchronous streaming of media on multiple browsers/devices

Tags: http-live-streaming

I already have some platform that has some prerecorded video files (mkvs to be precise).
Now i need to make "collaborative watch" and most important and tricky part is that they should be completely synchronized (delta up to 100ms is acceptable, i think) and controllable by any side (any watcher can play/pause).

I already checked out WebRTC and I doubt it can provide the quality of HLS streaming, what is acceptable for calls, but not for HD watching.

Bare HLS delta can vary up to full chunk length, but i think it could be implemented using websockets to communicate between server and client and something like video metadata.

Actual questions are:

Is there any good example of synchronization of multiple clients?

If not, how i can control  tag to precisely position, stop and start videos via js or rust?

Also, can i buffer playback to ensure that no one waits for new video parts from server?

If it is important, currently server written in haskell, and I can use whatever I want on the client side (but I prefer rust with yew)

Answer (score 2):

The good news is that while you need playback synchronization, you *don't* need low latency playback.  Therefore, all the quality tradeoffs made for WebRTC media streaming do not apply to your use case.

Stream the video using whatever streaming tech you want.  This could be a simple `<video>` tag with the `src` set to the URL of your MKV.  (Assuming codec compatibility, and clients able to keep up-to-speed with the bitrate.  Otherwise, consider transcoding to a bunch of HLS segments and serving that way.)

Then, to keep the video in-sync, you just need a clock source.  You can't use the PC clock directly since everyone's clocks are out of sync.  But, you can send a time offset periodically.  Use any method you want... I would use SSE/EventSource.  The client connects, the server sends a message indicating what timestamp the player should be at, and then the player goes to there.

If you're 10+ seconds away from where you should be, simply seek the video by setting `currentTime`.  Though if you're closer, change the playback rate to drift it back to where it should be.